# React createElement not working return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple code I'm trying to use `replace prototype` to replace the old content and create new element with new content.

For example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'bold'
    };
  }
  replace = () =>{
    let oldState = this.state.name;
    oldState = oldState.replace(/bold/i, React.createElement('b',{ children: 'withBold'}) )
    console.log(oldState)
    this.setState({ name: oldState})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.replace}>Click</button><br />
       {this.state.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('code'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='code'></div>
```

I have tried `document.createElement` I got `[object HTMLElement]`

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish. `oldState.replace(/bold/i, 'withBold')` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @Tholle Hi, I'm trying to create a DOM element, it should be like `<b>withBold</b>`

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.replace` expects the replacement value to be a string or function. You're passing in an object (`React.createElement(...)`).

Your issue is here:

```
oldState = oldState.replace(
    /bold/i,
    // The following must be a string, but you are passing in an object:
    React.createElement('b',{ children: 'withBold'})
);
```

There are many ways to solve this.
Personally, for such a simple case, I would just write:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    name: prevState.name.toLowerCase() === 'bold'
        ? <b>withBold</b>
        : prevState.name
});
```